# Show line chart and scatter chart in one VizFrame

Tags: sapui5, scatter-plot

I have VizFrame scatter chart and I need to add there some data represented by line. I was trying to do this by adding reference line ([plotArea.referenceLine.line](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Scatter%20%20(5)/Scatter%20Plot/)), but it looks like the input can be just one value for this property, so the reference line is always perpendicluar one the axis (please see [example](http://jsbin.com/japufokebo/1/edit?html,output)).

The data I would like to add as a line are saved under the "Line" name:

```
var oData =  [
                {                     
                    "Z": "A",
                    "X": 171.9,
                    "Y": 183,
                    "Line": 176.7
                },
                {                    
                    "Z": "B",
                    "X" : 144.3,
                    "Y": 158.6,
                    "Line": 163.3
                },
             //....and so on, more in the example
}];
```

Is there any way how to show line chart and scatter chart in one [VizFrame](http://jsbin.com/japufokebo/1/edit?html,output)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VizFrame supports "combined" charts. Unfortunately, I don't think that you can combine scatter and line charts. Check our my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014985/7612556.

> - You cannot add "oblique" reference lines (= the trend line) to the chart. You can only add vertical / horizontal ones via the [Reference Line](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.ReferenceLine/preview) feature. Check out the (non-intuitive) documentation on this: [Viz Charts Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Scatter%20%20(5)/Scatter%20Plot/) (look at the plotArea.referenceLine.line; it is just a number = will be a horizontal / vertical line depending on your chart type or orientation).
> - You cannot combine a scatter plot with a line chart. If you look in the same [Viz Charts Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Scatter%20%20(5)/Scatter%20Plot/), you will see that in the Combination "chapter" on the left hand side, there is no "Line - Scatter" combination.

Comment: Thanks Serban, it seems reasonable, but I wait few days if someone comes  with some solution (I see that probably it is not possible). If not I will accept your answer. If yes I will upvote.